# Как декодировать сообщение пришедшее из класса Process по InputStream

Tags: java, кодировка

Вот такой код:

```
Process proc = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("ipconfig");
proc.waitFor();
InputStream in = proc.getInputStream();
byte[] input_bytes = new byte[in.available()];
for (int i = 0; i < input_bytes.length; i++) {
    input_bytes[i] = (byte)in.read();
}
String input_string = new String(input_bytes, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
System.out.println(input_string);
```

Я запустил утилиту ipconfig, подождал пока она выполнится, после чего достал из процесса `InputStream`, прочитал все доступные байты из него, попытался их декодировать в строку, запустил программу, но вместо кириллицы он пишет знаки � и другие непонятные.

Пытался использовать разные кодировки, US_ASCII, UTF-16 и т. д., кириллицу все равно не декодирует.
Скорее всего, проблема в том, что коды кириллицы не вмещаются в диапазон `byte`, но, хоть метод `in.read()` и возвращает `int`, над методом стоит аннотация `@Range(from = -1, to = 255)`, да и в конструктор класса `String` можно запихнуть лишь массив байтов

Можно ли как то это исправить и правильно декодировать кириллицу?  Предлагайте любые способы, рассмотрю всё!

Comment: Проблема может быть как в вашей DOS консоли, поддерживающей старую байтовую кодировку CP866, так и в использовании байтового потока ввода/вывода `InputStream` вместо символьного потока `InputStreamReader`.

Comment: _в конструктор класса String можно запихнуть лишь массив байтов_ Это не так, есть [конструкторы `String(char[] arr)`, `String(char[] arr, int offset, int count)`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/String.html#%3Cinit%3E(char%5B%5D)), принимающие символьные массивы, и соответственно разновидность, принимающая целочисленный массив кодовых точек [`String(int[] codePoints, int offset, int count)`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/String.html#%3Cinit%3E(int%5B%5D,int,int))

Comment: @NowhereMan так `InputStreamReader` работает поверх `inputStream`, он же как то эти байты преобразовывает, байтовый поток ввода/вывода в символьный, вот и я решил не использовать готовые инструменты, а во всём разобраться сам.
Насчет конструктора, если в него запихнуть массив `int`, то он декодируется в кодировке Unicode, без возможности её изменить, а мне нужно декодировать в другой кодировке, так что это плохой пример

Answer (score -1):

Собственно в чём проблема, я разобрался, нужно было всего лишь использовать кодировку 866

Comment: Не является ответом на вопрос. Чтобы оставить свои замечания или попросить у автора внести уточнения, оставьте комментарий к соответствующему сообщению. — [из очереди проверок](/review/low-quality-posts/847213)

Comment: @ksa так это же автор сам и ответил на свой вопрос. В вопросе фигурировало "пытался использовать разные кодировки", в ответе он указал, какая кодировка ему в итоге помогла. Ответ хоть и короткий, но вроде как "проблему" решает.